# Can i put yeast into cookie dough to make them thicker looking?

Tags: baking, cookies

I want to make cookies thicker looking can i add some yeast into cookies dough to make them thicker.

Comment: i specifically ask for adding yeast

Comment: This is not a duplicate by any means.  The fact that most cookies include baking powder and that you can't very well mix it with yeast is one part of the answer, but not all.  Another reason would be that yeast results in a very different texture, one not usually associated with cookies.  Another would be that if cookies were much fatter the baking time/temperature would need to be very different.

Comment: The need for a strongly gluten-based dough when using a slow leavener like yeast is well explained in the referenced question... shortbread, which is what most kinds of cookies are based on, is the very opposite of a strongly gluten-based dough...